# Проблема с ajax запросом при парсинге Comfy.ua

Tags: ajax, php, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый день.

Есть сайт comfy.ua, на котором есть возможность выбора города (справа вверху).
Так вот проблема с изменением этого города. Не могу понять, какие и где параметры передаются, чтоб можно было их самому передавать.

Подсказали, что передаются city_id и URL - http://comfy.ua/region_prices/select/city методом пост.

Кто-то может подсказать, как это реализовать? То есть мне нужно получить страницу с измененным городом, а дальше парсить не составит труда.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@paluchh](/users/24682/paluchh)](/users/24682/paluchh), пробуйте так

```
// Выбираем кород
$url = "http://comfy.ua/region_prices/select/city";
$city_id= 1466; // ID города (Херсон)
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"city_id=".$city_id);
$output = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);

// запрос на главную с уже выбранным городом
$ch = curl_init('http://comfy.ua');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$out = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $out;
curl_close ($ch);
```

> жаль что я не программист

Зачем тогда взялись за это? )) Наняли б уже специалиста

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, после "гуглирования" пришел почти к такому же результату. :) А почему не нанять специалиста? Ну, все-таки самому интересно напрягать свои мозги, пусть и с чьей-то помощью, и к тому же для парсинга нужных мне сайтов базовых понятий в php вполне хватало, вот до Комфи. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, курлом вам нужно сделать пост запрос на сайт, http://comfy.ua/region_prices/select/city, сюда с параметрами data-id - номер города, и переменной city_id. Ответом будет как раз то, что вам нужно.

Comment: сделал вот так:
$url = "http://comfy.ua/region_prices/select/city";
    $city_id= 678;
    $ch = curl_init();  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest", "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"data-id=".$city_id);
   
    $output = curl_exec($ch);  
    curl_close($ch);  
    echo $output; 

в итоге получил:
{"status":"error"}

Comment: @paluchh, я, вроде, нормально описал, что там постом нужно передавать 2 параметра, а вы передаете один.

Comment: @paluchh, Ключ не  data-id, а city_id

В заголовке оставьте только:

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"));

Comment: поменял, получил:
{"status":"success"}
а как теперь получить страницу которую нужно парсить?

Comment: @paluchh, эта операция не относится к конкретной странице. Дальше вам самому нужно указывать то, что парсить хотите: толи отдельную страницу, толи весь сайт в целом.

Comment: Не, ну я понял, что мы в теории передали параметры обработчику этих городов. Но вот если вставить после того кода что-то типа этого:

    $url_sch='http://comfy.ua';
        $content = file_get_contents($url_sch);
        echo $content;

мы получаем не измененный город.

Comment: @paluchh, я так понимаю, что город, после его выбора, сохраняется в cookie. Делаем вывод - последующие запросы отправлять с печеньками.

Comment: Спасибо большое, жаль, что я не программист, буду рыть теперь, как отправлять запросы с cookie.